# What happens when an interrupt power changes the situation? 4e

Tags: dnd-4e

One of the characters in the party is a Knight with slide 2 on their Melee basic. The general consensus in the group is that when an enemy attacks one of the knight's allies, the knight successfully interrupts (using his battle guardian attack) and slides the enemy out of range for their attack, they lose the action, since it can't be completed.

However today a situation came up where the enemy announced their attack against an ally of the knight, within the knight's aura, and the opportunity action attack from the knight hit, sliding the enemy, but because the enemy had reach, they were still in range to attack somebody, just not the original target, so the DM ruled the enemy could still make the attack it started against the different target.

We just rolled with it, but I'm not sure if that's the right ruling, or even where to look for the rules that would cover this (the opportunity action and immediate interrupt rules don't seem to go into it).

Comment: I edited the first paragraph to make it slightly less awkward to read, but I might have messed things up. Can you check?

Comment: No, that looks better to me. Cheers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Interrupts: An immediate interrupt jumps in when its trigger occurs, taking place before the trigger finishes. **If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, the triggering action is lost.** (RC p195 emphasis mine).

The triggering action in the case that you describe is the attempt to attack your specific ally. If the ally is no longer in range, the enemy cannot select a new target (if they still had reach to the *same* target they could continue the attack).